# HTTPClient to API, Certificate and SSL errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I've created a ASP.Net Core 2.1 web application which gathers data from two sources. One is a SQL-database which supplies data via Entity Framework to my application. This one works fine. The other source is a REST API. I'm having troubles connecting to this.

I'm calling this Task which should return a user via his/hers e-mail address:

```
        public async Task<PersonsModel> ReturnPersonByEmail(string email)
    {
        const string apiKey = "xxx";

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://xx.xxx.xxxx.xx:xxx/xxxx/xxx/xx/xx/person/?email={email}");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("x-api-key", "123456");
            var url = new Uri(client.BaseAddress.ToString());

            string json = "";

            try
            {
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

                using (var content = response.Content)
                {
                    json = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var exception = e;
            }

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PersonsModel>(json);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try calling it via Postman client.GetAsync(url) always returns an exception:

**Message = "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."
Message = "The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception."**

I tried adding the following codesegment to launchSettings.json(as per a reply to a similar question posted here: [HttpClient client.GetAsync works in full .Net framework but not in .Net core 2.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51678695/httpclient-client-getasync-works-in-full-net-framework-but-not-in-net-core-2-1/51679276) )         *"DOTNET_SYSTEM_NET_HTTP_USESOCKETSHTTPHANDLER": "0"* and then I get another error:

**Message = "Error 12175 calling WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_REQUEST_ERROR, 'A security error has occurred'."**

If you have any idea on what might cause this problem I would be very grateful for any help. Thanks!

Comment: Problem would be with your signed certificate or its properties like name etc. If you only need for debugging then you can bypass it. For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777607/the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure-using

Comment: Thanks for the reply however if I just disable certificate validation as per the link you posted I get the **WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_REQUEST**-error I stated before. So to my eyes this doesn't seem to be a certificate validation error but an error in the asynchronous call?

Comment: Solved this issue with the solution stated in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43265186/net-core-api-post-exception-gives-nativeerrorcode-12175.